# Mulitipicklist filtering in dynamic page

Tags: lightning, page-layout, dynamic

Can I apply a filter on a field in a dynamic page with the options chosen in another multi-picklist field?
It will work for a normal picklist but for multi picklist is it possible?
When I checked I found it was not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, it's not possible the easy way.

One way would be to create formula fields for each and every value in the multi-picklist and use these formula fields to control your dynamic form. However, you can also evaluate the future scaleability of such an approach and whether you want to keep the multi-picklist in place or change it to something else

Here what I mean:

Let's say you have 10 options for the multi-picklist. Then you can create 10 Formula fields Checkbox (boolean) as follows:

```
IF (INCLUDES ( MultiPicklistName__c , "Value 1" ), true, false )
```

and the same for each value in your multi-picklist. One thing is that if multiple values are giving the same result, you can have one formula to check if any of the values is selected.

Not the best solution, but it is what it is :)

P.S. One important note here. If you want to control Dynamic Form - changes will appear only after the User save changes in the multipi-
cklist.

Comment: P.S. `IF(condition, true, false)` is the same as `condition` as far as formulas are concerned. If you already have a Boolean return value (e.g. `INCLUDES`), you don't also need the `IF` function.